# Extract every element except every n-th element of vector

Tags: matlab, indexing

Given a vector

```
A = [1,2,3,...,100]
```

I want to extract all elements, except every n-th. So, for n=5, my output should be

```
B = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,...]
```

I know that you can access every n-th element by

```
A(5:5:end)
```

but I need something like the inverse command.
If this doesn't exist I would iterate over the elements and skip every n-th entry, but that would be the dirty way.

Comment: read my answer, the "inverse command" you look for exists. Logical indexing is an important part of Matlab, and a very important feature to know and use.

Comment: given the help of all of you, I guess this is even more what i was looking for:

    A(mod(1:100,5)~=0)
thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can eliminate elements like this:

```
A = 1:100;
removalList = 1:5:100;
A(removalList) = [];
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a mask. Let's say you have

```
A = 1 : 100;
```

Then

```
m = mod(0 : length(A) - 1, 5);
```

will be a vector of the same length as `A` containing the repeated sequence `0 1 2 3 4`.
You want everything from A except the elements where `m == 4`, i.e.

```
B = A(m ~= 4);
```

will result in

```
B == [1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 16 ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use logical indexing:

```
n = 5; % remove the fifth
idx = logical(zeroes(size(A))); % creates a blank mask
idx(n) = 1; % makes the nth element 1
A(idx) = []; % ta-da!
```

About the "inversion" command you cited, it is possible to achieve that behavior using logical indexing. You can negate the vector to transform every 1 in 0, and vice-versa.

So, this code will remove any BUT the fifth element:

```
negatedIdx = ~idx;
A(negatedIdx) = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use it like this?

say A is your vector

```
A = 1:100
n = 5
B = A([1:n-1,n+1:end])
```

then

```
B=[1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 10 ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for your problem is the function [`setdiff()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html).

In your specific case, the solution would be:

```
lenA = length(A);
index = setdiff(1:lenA,n:n:lenA);
B = A(index)
```

If you do it all at once, you can avoid both extra variables:

```
B = A( setdiff(1:end,n:n:end) )
```

However, [Logical Indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) is a faster option, as [tested](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/41762-delete-row-from-matrix#answer_51471):

```
lenA = length(A);
index = true(1, lenA);
index(n:n:lenA) = false;
B = A(index)
```

All these codes assume that you have specified the variable `n`, and can adapt to a different value.

Answer (score 0):

For the shortest amount of code, you were nearly there all ready. If you want to adjust your existing array use:

```
A(n:n:end)=[];
```

Or if you want a new array called B:

```
B=A;
B(n:n:end)=[];
```