# Select all elements except one in a vector

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469718/extract-every-element-but-the-nth-element-of-vector) but I can't manage exactly how to apply that answer to my problem.

I am looping through a vector with a variable `k` and want to select the whole vector except the single value at index `k`.

Any idea?

```
for k = 1:length(vector)

   newVector = vector( exluding index k);    <---- what mask should I use? 
   % other operations to do with the newVector

end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`vector([1:k-1 k+1:end])` will do. Depending on the other operations, there may be a better way to handle this, though.

For completeness, if you want to remove one element, you do not need to go the `vector = vector([1:k-1 k+1:end])` route, you can use `vector(k)=[];`

Comment: @Matteo Enter `[1:0 2:5]` and see whether it outputs what you want. ;-) (The `end` keyword will not work when not trying to index a vector.)

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works out perfectly, and also thanks for the tip on `vector(k)=[];`

Comment: @LuisMendo I mean that you cannot test what `[1:k-1 k+1:end]` will give you for some `k` alone, outside `vector([1:k-1 k+1:end])`, hence I used `5` as a fixed end in the example of testing what `1:0` might be.

Answer (score 30):

Another alternative without `setdiff`() is

```
vector(1:end ~= k)
```

Comment: Good call.  Logical indexing is usually preferable and this works great if you just have a scalar `k` as in the question.

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun, here's an interesting way with [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html):

```
vector(setdiff(1:end,k))
```

What's interesting about this, besides the use of `setdiff`, you ask?  Look at the placement of `end`.  MATLAB's [`end` keyword](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html) translates to the last index of `vector` in this context, even as an argument to a function call rather than directly used with `paren` (`vector`'s `()` operator). No need to use `numel(vector)`.  Put another way,

```
>> vector=1:10;
>> k=6;
>> vector(setdiff(1:end,k))
ans =
     1     2     3     4     5     7     8     9    10
>> setdiff(1:end,k)
Error using setdiff (line 81)
Not enough input arguments.
```

That is not completely obvious IMO, but it can come in handy in many situations, so I thought I would point this out.

Answer (score 2):

Very easy:

```
newVector = vector([1:k-1 k+1:end]);
```

This works even if `k` is the first or last element.

Answer (score 2):

```
%create a logic vector of same size:
l=ones(size(vector))==1;
l(k)=false;
vector(l);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! it works but I'll stick with the other ones cause they involve less variables.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do this which allows you to exclude multiple indices at once (or a single index... basically it's robust to allow either) is:

```
newVector = oldVector(~ismember(1:end,k))
```

Works just like `setdiff` really, but builds a logical mask instead of a list of explicit indices.