# What are the semantics of 'end' in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, indexing

It's common to use the `end` keyword as a shortcut for accessing or extending an array in Matlab, as in

```
>> x = [1,2,3];
>> x(1:end-1)
ans =
    1   2
>> x(end+1) = 4
x =
    1   2   3   4
```

However, I was surprised to find that the following also works

```
>> x(1:min(5, end))
ans =
    1   2   3   4
```

I thought that `end` might be a special form, like `:`, that can be special-cased in indexing operations, so I created a class to detect this

```
classdef IndexDisplayer
  methods
    function subsref(self, s)
      disp(s);
    end
  end
end
```

You can see how `:` is special cased in the following example

```
>> a = IndexDisplayer;
>> a(1:3)
    type: '()'
    subs: {[1 2 3]}
>> a(:)
    type: '()'
    subs: {':'}
```

However, when I index with `end` I just see

```
>> a(end)
    type: '()'
    subs: {[1]}
```

Here the `end` is replaced with a `1`. Where does that `1` come from? My first guess was that any `end` inside an indexing expression `x(end)` would be replaced with a call to `length(x)` so I tried overriding `length` as well

```
classdef IndexDisplayer
  methods
    function subsref(self, s)
      disp(s);
    end
    function len = length(self)
      len = 10;
    end
  end
end
```

However, that gives

```
>> a = IndexDisplayer;
>> length(a)
ans =
    10
>> a(end)
    type: '()'
    subs: {[1]}
```

so that theory is out the window. Can anyone explain the semantics of `end`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly, I think it's kind of a bug, or at least an unexpected feature, that your syntax `x(1:min(5, end))` works at all. When I was at MathWorks, I remember someone pointing this out, and quite a few of the developers had to spend a while figuring out what was going on. I'm not sure if they ever really agreed whether it was a problem or not.

To explain the (intended) semantics of `end`: `end` is implemented as a function `ind = end(obj, k, n)`. `k` is the index of the expression containing `end`, and `n` is the total number of indices in the expression.

So, for example, when you call `a(1,end,1)`, `k` is 2, as the `end` is in argument 2, and `n` is 3 as there are 3 arguments.

`ind` is returned as the index that can replace `end` in the expression.

You can overload `end` for your own classes (in the same way as you can overload `colon`, `size`, `subsref` etc).

To extend your example:

```
classdef IndexDisplayer
  methods
    function ind = end(self,k,n)
        disp(k)
        disp(n)
        ind = builtin('end', self, k, n);
    end
  end
end

>> a = IndexDisplayer;
>> a(1,end,1)
 2
 3
```

See [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/indexed-reference-and-assignment.html#br1dtdk-1) for more information.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I suppose that the default `end` for objects just returns `1`? I'd be interested to find out how it works in the case of `x(1:min(5,end))`. Do you walk up the call tree until you find an object for which the `end` function is defined?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is happening with `x(1:min(5,end))`, and I'm not sure you could definitively find out unless you had access to the internals of MATLAB. It's not obvious to me how it chooses which `end` function to dispatch to when it's in an expression like that. For example, if you redefine `min` to be an array, `end` seems to refer to the end of the array `min`, not the end of `x`, and I can't really explain why. You may need to ask MathWorks, although I'm not sure anyone except a couple of developers would be able to give you a full explanation.

Comment: If you're lucky, @Edric might hear this batcall and explain things better than I can...

Comment: PS You also asked whether the default `end` for objects just returns 1. An object is just a scalar array (of size (1,1)), so yes, when called on just an object, it would return 1. But if called on an array of objects of different size, it would return whatever was appropriate - unless you've overloaded `end` for that class. There's an example in the doc of a class that has a `Data` property, where `end` is overloaded to return information about `Data` rather than the object itself. When doing that you would have to be very careful to get the correct behavior when called on an array of objects.

Comment: Someone in Mathworks tech support essentially confirmed that this is undocumented behaviour, and shouldn't be relied upon (in particular, it could disappear or change behaviour in later versions of MATLAB). I'll mark this accepted for now.

Answer (score 4):

I find this a curiosity too. Nevertheless, I often use (exploit?) this behavior to shorten statements. For example, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19599429/2778484), to get all but the `k`th element(s) of a vector, a clean solution that occurred to me was,

```
vector(setdiff(1:end,k))
```

This `end` replaces a call to `numel(vector)`. For a scalar `k`, this is an alternative to `vector(1:end ~= k)` or `vector([1:k-1 k+1:end])`.  It seemed perfectly reasonable at the time, although I drew attention to the oddity of this usage.  Is this really bad practice? Perhaps, but I've accepted it for what it's worth and move on.

I don't offer any insight into how this works or what the rules are, as Sam Roberts does in his answer, but conceptually, I see this as a matter of context. That is, when `end` occurs, I would assume it evaluates to an index (or dimension subscript) for the *array* with the most immediate scope, looking "up" through nested statements to make the determination.  Not sure if that is the right wording, but it seems to be a useful way to interpret the operation of [`end`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html).

I haven't been bitten by this interpretation yet.

Comment: I just wandered around here. Just wanted to point you to [the comment by OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016606/what-are-the-semantics-of-end-in-matlab#comment35248138_23017087) 3 days after your post (just in case you missed it): this is officially undocumented behaviour.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I did see that thanks.  I should say that I would only use such a statement in the interactive MATLAB command prompt, NOT when writing functions or scripts that you hope to use in the future.