# Extract Sequence of Rows in Column (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, row, sequence

I am trying to extract a sequence of rows from a column of data in MATLAB.  For example, my data looks like this in one column:

```
10 
20 
30 
40 
50 
60 
70 
80 
90 
100 
110 
120 
130
```

I want to select a sequence of rows and store these rows in a column vector `A` that looks like this after extracting the first 3 rows skipping 2 rows then selecting the next 3 rows and skipping 2 rows and selecting the next 3 to the end of the column.

Finally, the data should look like this with `9 rows and 1 column`:

```
10 
20
30
60 
70 
80
110 
120
130
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

```
x = [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120 130].'; %'// data
m = 3; %// keep
n = 2; %// skip
```

Then

```
y = x(mod(0:end-1,m+n)<=m-1);
```

or equivalently

```
y = x(mod(0:numel(x)-1,m+n)<=m-1);
```

*How this works*: generate the sequence `0,1,2,... numel(x)-1`. Each number corresponds to a position in `x`. To keep `m` and skip `n` cyclically, you apply `mod(...,m+n)` to that sequence. For example, for `m=3`,  `n=2` the result is sequence `0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,...`. You then select those numbers (that is, the corresponding entries of `x`) that are `<=m-1`. This results in the periodic pattern "keep, keep, keep, skip, skip".

---

To first skip and then keep (reverse from above): just reverse the inequality:

```
y = x(mod(0:end-1,m+n)>=m-1);
```

or

```
y = x(mod(0:numel(x)-1,m+n)>=m-1);
```

Comment: Nice thing is the [use of `end` within `mod`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016606/what-are-the-semantics-of-end-in-matlab) :-)

Comment: Exactly, which was missing when calculating indices separately with my  `bsxfun` :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming `a` is your input column vector -

```
r_accept = 3; %// number of rows to accept
r_reject = 2; %// number of rows to reject

ind1 = bsxfun(@plus,1:r_accept+r_reject:numel(a),[0:r_accept-1]') %//'
out = a(ind1(ind1(:)<=numel(a))) %// desired output
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out another way to compliment the nice solutions using `find` function.

If my data is:

```
x = [10; 20; 30; 40; 50; 60; 70; 80; 90; 100; 110; 120; 130]
```

and I want to extract a repeating sequence of rows then:
Develop an index of the repeating pattern or row sequence of keeps (3) and skips (2) rows.  My index would be then:

```
index = [1:5 1:5 1:5]
```

or

```
index = 123451234512345
```

Then use the `find` function to logically index the "keep" sequence.

```
a = find(index<4)
```

which gives:

```
a = 1 2 3 6 7 8 11 12 13
```

then:

```
b = x(a)
```

produces

```
b = 10 20 30 60 70 80 110 120 130
```