# Matlab finding three elements in the middle of a matrix

Tags: matlab

Lets say I have a matrix of x = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11]

I need to find the three middle numbers in that matrix (without counting or hard-coding) and assign it to a variable say y

So the y will be assigned the three middle elements in any data set.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Does this count as counting? `x(ceil(end/2)+[-1 0 1])`

Comment: middle number in index position? or middle number in value?  your example is dumb because index = value.  please clarify.  by the way, your x is a row vector.

Comment: @LuisMendo  you are the Evel Knievil of MATLAB... didn't even know ceil(end) was possible ... wow

Comment: What do you mean by counting?? `[x(4:6)]`??

Comment: I meant locating the elements like x(4:6) because if I import data, each data matrix will vary by size.  Maybe hard coding is the right word.

Comment: Thanks luis mendo that worked!

Comment: @TryHard - It's one of the less known constructs in MATLAB in terms of using it effectively.  If you use `end` within the scope of indexing, the numerical value defaults to the end of the array.  Still yes, very cool.

Comment: @TryHard :-) More about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016606/what-are-the-semantics-of-end-in-matlab)

Comment: @bullets I'm posting my comment as an answer then so that you can accept it

Answer (score 3):

To select the three entries in the middle of vector `x`, you can use

```
y = x(ceil(end/2)+[-1 0 1]);
```

More about this use of `end` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016606/what-are-the-semantics-of-end-in-matlab).