# How to understand the meaning of Matlab 'end' operator inside expression parameters

Tags: matlab

I have to adjust a matlab script and have a problem with this piece of code

```
if isOk()
    h = h(1+limit:end-limit, 1+limit:end-limit, :);
    limit= 0;
end
```

Unfortunately I haven't understood how to read the expression

```
 h = h(1+limit:end-limit, 1+limit:end-limit, :);
```

what is the meaning of `end` operator inside it?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html and read from *The special `end` operator is an easy shorthand way to refer to the last element of `v`*.

Comment: @CST-Link Thanks so so if `a:end` means from a to last... why the `, :` as third parameter of expression? What should mean `:` alone as parameter?

Comment: Try the link from CST-Link http://se.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html. I repeat it, just in case. Links are sent because they are supposed to be read. The whole article should not take more than 5 minutes.

Comment: @NicoLorio In the above link, read from *A single `:` in a subscript position is shorthand notation for `1:end` and is often used to select entire rows or columns*. P.S. It's all explained in the help, you just need to have the patience to read it. :-)

Comment: @NicoLorio Thinking about it, why not just try it straight away: `A = [11,12,13;21,22,23;31,32,33], A(1:end,1:2), A(1,:)`. You may as well try this when you are at it `A(:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `end` operator is just a shorthand for `length(var)`. You can even do stuff like var(1:end/2) to get the first half of your variable. 
For more than 1 dimension, the `end` operator acts as `size(var, x)`, where `x` is the current dimension.

**Attention:** Matlab **does not** use zero based indexing, i.e. accessing `array(length(array))` is actually correct. Hence the relation of `end` with the size of the variable is correct, since it is the **last index of the variable**, where the variable has one-based indexing.

So in Matlab you can even write stuff like

```
a= rand(4,8); a(1:end/2, 1:end/2);
```

If you leave all away, and just type `a(:)` (i.e. nothing before and after the `:`, then you actually mean `1:end`

```
(:) ==> (1:end)
```

Comment: You can even use `end` within functions to refer to an outer array (`x(1:min(end,4))`). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016606/what-are-the-semantics-of-end-in-matlab

Comment: I think you might avoid potential confusion on the part of folks coming from other programming languages if you said that `end` is shorthand for the last index for the given dimension. Relating `end` to `size` may mislead people used to zero-based indices into thinking that the last index is `end-1`.