# MATLAB OOP: How does the end function get called when passed to a class method

Tags: matlab, class, oop, methods

I have a class in MATLAB that uses a class method for specialized indexing into the class data. I am interested in overloading the end(obj, k, n) method so that it is easy to write indexing expressions into this method, but I have already overloaded this function for use in subsref(obj, s).

Could someone please explain to me how MATLAB calls the end method in the following:

```
>> obj = myClass; obj.myIndexMethod(1:end)
```

Comment: Is [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/object-end-indexing.html) not sufficient?

Comment: The documentation sufficiently explains what happens when you call `obj(1:end)`. No, it does not explain what happens when you pass `end` as part of an argument to a class method.

Comment: To clarify, `myIndexMethod` is a method of my class, not a property.

Answer (score 1):

`end` is implemented as a function `ind = end(obj, k, n)`. `k` is the index of the expression containing `end`, and `n` is the total number of indices in the expression.

So, for example, when you call `a(1,end,1)`, `k` is 2, as the `end` is in argument 2, and `n` is 3 as there are 3 arguments.

`ind` is returned as the index that can replace `end` in the expression.

Comment: Yes, I already understand how end is supposed to work when you use it in an indexing expression. What I do not understand is how it is called when you pass it as part of an argument to a function.

Comment: As I said in my original question, I've already overloaded end to work correctly when indexing into my class.

Comment: `end` is a method that is intended for use in an indexing expression only. It doesn't really make sense to use in another context, such as an argument to a method, but if you do, it still works in the same way anyway. If (instead of `a(1,end,1)` as above), you call `a.myMethod(1,end,1)`, MATLAB will pass `k` as 2 and `n` as 3 into the `end` method of `a`. If the `end` method is builtin, it will return `ind` as above, and if you overload it, it will return whatever you tell it to.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016606/what-are-the-semantics-of-end-in-matlab