# Matlab: Cut matrix in half correctly for signal processing

Tags: matlab, matrix, signal-processing

I am working on a signal processing Matlab project.  I am performing an FFT and cutting the matrix in half to only get the single sided spectrum.  I use the following lines of code and get the error "Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as index 
":

```
amp = abs(y).^2/n;    % amplitude of the DFT
amp = amp(1:end/2);
```

To get rid of the warning I tried to manually round it, but when I do that I get the error "Error using round
Not enough input arguments."

```
amp = abs(y).^2/n;    % amplitude of the DFT
amp = amp(1:round(end/2));
```

What I am wondering is what is the correct way to cut the matrix in half for the single sided spectrum?  As a side note this is the whole piece of code:

```
clear all;

% Read Audio
fs = 44100;         % sample frequency (Hz)
full = audioread('song.wav');

% Remove leading 0's and select range
for i = 1:fs
    if full(i) ~= 0
        crop = i;
        break
    end
end
full = full(crop:end);

startTime = 1;
endTime = 5;

% Play song
tic
initialTime = toc;
player = audioplayer(full(fs*startTime:fs*endTime), fs);
player.play();

% Perform fft and get frequencies (hopefully in realish time with audio)
windowSize = fs/16;
for i = windowSize/2+1+fs*(startTime-1) : fs/32 : fs*endTime
    beginningChunk = round(i-windowSize/2);
    endChunk = round(i+windowSize/2);

    x = full(beginningChunk:endChunk);
    y = fft(x);
    n = length(x);     % number of samples in chunk
    amp = abs(y).^2/n;    % amplitude of the DFT
    amp = amp(1:round(end/2));
    f = (0:n-1)*(fs/n);     % frequency range
    f = f(1:round(end/2));
    while initialTime+i/fs > toc
        pause(.0001);
    end
    figure(1);
    plot(f,amp);
    axis([0 10000 0 5]);
    xlabel('Frequency');
    ylabel('amplitude');
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `amp(1:round(end/2))` doesn't work for you (it seem to work on R2017a), then try `amp(1:round(length(amp)/2))` instead. (Or better, use `floor`.)

Note that `end` in this case is strictly `numel(amp)` because you use linear indexing (indexing with one value). Because `amp` is a vector, `length` is the same.

In the general case, `A(end,end)`, the first end is equivalent to `size(A,1)` and the second one to `size(A,2)`.

---

A second reason that you could be getting the error is if you have a custom function called `round`. Type `which round` on the MATLAB command prompt to find out what is called when you type `round(1)`.

Comment: _`round(end/2)` therefore has no meaning_. That's not correct. Try `x=[10 20 30]; x(round(end/2))`

Comment: @LuisMendo: That blew my mind. Has that always worked? -- Anyway, thanks, I've fixed the post.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit [surprising, but works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23016606/2586922)