# Create a d-dimensional tensor dynamically

Tags: matlab, tensor

I would like to create a d-dimensional tensor using `d` as an input and without the `if` statement as below:

```
if d == 2
   B = zeros(r,r);
   for i = 1:r
       B(i,i) = 1;
   end                
elseif d == 3
   B = zeros(r,r,r);
   for i = 1:r
       B(i,i,i) = 1;
   end
end
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Did you read the documentation to `zeros`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [accumarray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
f = @(d,r)accumarray(repmat((1:r).',1 , d), 1);

> f(2,5)
=
1   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   1
```

Here is the basic signature of accumarray:

```
accumarray( subs , val )
```

Using `accumarray` we can create an n-dimensional array where `subs` represents the position of points that will be filled in the array and `val` represents the value of them.

If `subs` provided as a matrix , its number of columns determines the number of dimensions of the resultant array and each row represents position of each point.

For example for `d = 2` and `r = 5` we want to create a `(5 x 5)` array that has 1s in the following positions: `[1 1],[2 2],[3 3],[4 4],[5 5]`.

Using `repmat` we can create `subs`:

```
subs = repmat ((1:5).' , 1, 2)

=
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
```

`val` is set to `1` so all specified positions will be filled by `1`.

[.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127904/n-dimensional-identity-matrix/127916#127916)

Comment: Nice trick! As a side note, I believe that some explanation of what is going on could raise the educational value of this answer.

Answer (score 3):

This does what you want for arbitrary `r` and `d`:

```
B = zeros(repmat(r,1,d)); % initiallize as d×d×···×d array filled with 0
B(linspace(1,end,r)) = 1; % write 1 in the "diagonal". end can be replaced by r^d
```

Some notes on how it works:

- [`zeros`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html) can take a vector as input, which allows the number of dimensions to be specified dynamically.
- [Linear indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) is being used to specify the positions containing `1`.
- [`end`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html) is being used within a function call. This is a [not very well known feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016606/what-are-the-semantics-of-end-in-matlab).

---

Equivalently, you can first build the array in linear form and then reshape it:

```
B = reshape(mod(1:r^d, (r^d-1)/(r-1))==1, repmat(r,1,d));
```

Notes:

- The step between entries containing `1`, in linear indexing, is `(r^d-1)/(r-1)`.
- [`reshape`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) allows a vector as input to specify dimensions, similar to `zeros`.

Comment: Efficient! Clever use of `end`.