# N-dimensional identity tensor in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

The function `eye` does not support N-dimensional arrays.

I would like to create a matrix such that

`I(i,j,:,:)=eye(3,3)`

in a vectorial fashion, without having to loop over `i` and `j`.

What is the best way to do this? I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/48251186/6579744 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `repmat` to repeat `eye` into the 3rd and 4th dimensions, and use `shiftdim` to shift the dimensions

```
% for i = 1 to M, and j = 1 to N
k = shiftdim( repmat( eye(3,3), 1, 1, M, N ), 2 );
```

The output is nasty, because MATLAB doesn't display >2D data very well, but here are a couple of tests:

```
% Test that a given i-j pair gives eye(3,3) in the 3rd and 4th dimension
isequal( k(1,2,:,:), reshape( eye(3,3), 1, 1, 3, 3 ) ); % = 1, passed
% Test I-j slices are equal and i/j are oriented correctly. Test with M ~= N
isequal( k( 1, 1, :, : ), k( M, N, :, : ) ); %  = 1, passed
```

And here is the actual output of a slice

```
% Below is equivalent to eye(3,3) in the 3rd and 4th dimensions
k(3,4,:,:)
ans(:,:,1,1) =
     1
ans(:,:,2,1) =
     0
ans(:,:,3,1) =
     0
ans(:,:,1,2) =
     0
ans(:,:,2,2) =
     1
ans(:,:,3,2) =
     0
ans(:,:,1,3) =
     0
ans(:,:,2,3) =
     0
ans(:,:,3,3) =
     1
```

Comment: I still have a problem with this. When N=1, it does not give me a 1x1x3x3 identity matrix, but just 3x3.

Comment: I have fixed by doing `I=zeros(N,N,3,3);` and then
    `I(:,:,:,:) = shiftdim(repmat(eye(3,3), 1, 1, N, N), 2);`