# How to exclude an element from a single column matrix?

Tags: matrix, vector, octave

I am currently learning Andrew Ng's machine learning from coursera. Now, in the regularization section of cost unction and gradient descent in Week 3, I need to exclude out the first element of theta matrix corresponding to theta0. I tried a dummy matrix on my command line:

```
a = [ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7]
a =1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
```

And I tried the following codes to get all elements of the matrix except the first one:

```
1. a(2,:)
```

Output: 2

```
2. a(2:,1)
```

Output: Parse Error: Syntax error

```
3. a(2:,1)
```

Output: Parse Error: Syntax error

```
4. a(2,:;1)
```

Output: Parse Error: Syntax error

```
5. a(2,::;1)
```

Output: Parse Error: Syntax error

```
6. a(2::,1)
```

Output: Parse Error: Syntax error

What code do I need to fulfill my operation? And what matrix method is it called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
a(2:end)
```

Result:

```
ans =

   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
```

For the general case of excluding any single element, see [Select all elements except one in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596268/select-all-elements-except-one-in-a-vector) (it is about Matlab, but the usage is the same in Octave as well).